# _str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) after migrations of mezzanine apps

Tags: django, mezzanine

During start of an Django mezzanine project, I am getting following message:

```
You have 7 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): auth, blog, conf, forms, galleries, mainapp, pages.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

I have not really noticed when/why it starts appearing. I have definitely not updated any library.

When I migrate, I get following error whenever I access any page:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
('mezzanine.boot',
 'modeltranslation',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'mezzanine.conf',
 'mezzanine.core',
 'mezzanine.generic',
 'mezzanine.pages',
 'mezzanine.blog',
 'mezzanine.forms',
 'mezzanine.galleries',
 'mezzanine.twitter',
 'mainapp',
 'filebrowser_safe',
 'grappelli_safe',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_comments')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/matous/PycharmProjects/webapps/iacah/app/templates/base.html, error at line 0
   __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)   1 : <!doctype html>
   2 : <html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}"{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %} dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
   3 : {% load pages_tags mezzanine_tags i18n staticfiles %}
   4 : 
   5 : <head>
   6 : <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   7 : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   8 : <meta name="keywords" content="{% block meta_keywords %}{% endblock %}">
   9 : <meta name="description" content="{% block meta_description %}{% endblock %}">
   10 : <title>{% block meta_title %}{% endblock %}{% if settings.SITE_TITLE %} | {{ settings.SITE_TITLE }}{% endif %}</title>


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  178.             response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)

File "/home/matous/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mezzanine/pages/middleware.py" in process_view
  90.                 return view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)

File "/home/matous/PycharmProjects/webapps/iacah/app/mainapp/views.py" in home
  36.             "news": news

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1040.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  708.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  849.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  911.                             current = current()

File "/home/matous/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mezzanine/core/models.py" in meta_title
  162.         return self._meta_title or getattr(self, "title", str(self))

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Before migrations, everything works perfectly. I use:

- Mezzanine 4.3.1
- Django 1.11
- Python 3.6.5
- SQLite 3.22.0
- Linux 4.15.0-33-generic

If I access the admin page after this migration, all pages has blank title (no title displayed and it is impossible to edit them nor delete.

Comment: have you tried applying the migrations?

Comment: @Incognos Yes, the problem occurs AFTER I apply the migrations.

Comment: looks like `settings.SITE_TITLE` is returning a `None` and therefore causing the error (might be that `settings` is `None` in the template